# Giving HTML form to FormData through event.target is throwing Argument of type 'EventTarget' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLFormElement'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to get the values from a `form` into `FormData`:

```
  const handleSubmit = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(e.target as HTMLFormElement);
    const value = formData.get('origin') ? 'open' : 'on';
    updateResizingOptionsQuery.mutate({ value });
  };
```

Since React sends `SynteticEvents`, the interface of `e.target` does not fit the `FormData` constructor. In the example, I'm casting the type which is not ideal. What would be a better version of that code?

Without casting this lint error is thrown:

> Argument of type 'EventTarget' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLFormElement'.
> Type 'EventTarget' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLFormElement': acceptCharset, action, autocomplete, elements, and 297 more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target` works. Because `currentTarget` always refers to the root event listener element, TypeScript knows it's the `<form>`:

```
import { FormEvent } from "react";
export default function App() {
const handleSubmit = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget);
  const value = formData.get("origin") ? "open" : "on";
  updateResizingOptionsQuery.mutate({ value });
};
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}></form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]